# El if solo me reconoce el ultimo elemento del array, que hago?

Tags: javascript, array, loops, if

```
function comenzar(){
    var caja=document.getElementById("caja");
    var numero=document.getElementById("numero");

    numero.addEventListener("change",background,false);

    setInterval(background(),50);
}
function background(){
     valores=[1,3,5];
        for (i=0; i<valores.length;i++){

        if (numero.value == valores[i]){
            caja.style.background="red";
        }
        else{caja.style.background="#000";}
        }
}
window.addEventListener("load",comenzar,false);
```

Comment: Hola Zerlink, bienvenido. Puedes añadir también el HTML asociado a tus funciones para ver donde puede estar el problema? Un saludo

Comment: 1. ¿Sabías que si no usas `var` o aún mejor, `const` o `let` al declarar una variable, aún ésta sea parte del control de un loop, automáticamente dicha variable se hace global? Empieza por erradicar esa muy mala práctica.

2. ¿Sabías que `setInterval` acepta como primer parámetro **una función** y que **él se encargará de ejecutarla**? Por ende, **no ejecutes la función** `background`, solo pásala como tal. Si la ejecutas, **solo se ejecutará una vez**.

Comment: @Zerlink expon bien la situación que se te presenta y el código (lo más que sea posible) que interviene para entender que quieres hacer y poder apoyarte. Ese "numero.value" ¿que es? por que en función "comenzar" tienes declarada una pero es local a la función no a la página; igual una leida al ámbito de declaración y su comportamiento te será de gran ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Independientemente de los otros errores que comentan, el principal error por el cual crees que solo se ejecuta el ultimo if se debe a que estas comparando valores diferentes `"numero.value"` es string, `valors[i]` es Integer y ademas que no sales del for con `break;` una vez que la condiciones es cierta para lograr el efecto que deseas.

Haz la siguiente corrección y te funcionara:

```js
function comenzar(){
    var caja=document.getElementById("caja");
    var numero=document.getElementById("numero");

    numero.addEventListener("change",background,false);

    setInterval(background(),50);
}
function background(){
     valores=[1,3,5];
        for (i=0; i<valores.length;i++){
        if (parseInt(numero.value) == valores[i]){
            caja.style.background="red";
            break;
        }
        else{caja.style.background="#000";}
        }
}
window.addEventListener("load",comenzar,false);
```

```html
<input id="caja">
<input id="numero">
```